# PHP artisan migrate:refresh is delete all present data from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I use the PHP artisan `migrate:refresh` command, it deletes my old data from other tables every time.

What should I do for that so that my migrate is run successfully and my old data is not erased?

Answer (score 12):

This is the expected behavior.

Migrate refresh will remove all tables, then reinstall all migrations. So any data will be lost.

If you want to add further migrations to your current database - you should just be running `php artisan migrate` - which will only run migrations that have not yet occurred.

Comment: @Dipesh Shihora - did that help with your question? Do you need more info?

Comment: but I need to change existing table then?

Comment: @DipeshShihora What do you mean? What are you trying to achieve? You change your existing tables via migrations (`php artisan migrate`), if you need to change anything about your database structure, you simply add one more migration - that's the whole point. You don't need to change anything manually

Comment: migrate:refresh This also deletes all your files that you have uploaded to Storage folder

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change your database but you dont want your old data to be erase, you have to add your database modification through another migration file. For example, if you want to add a field to a table (let's say add 'address' field to 'users' table) which already has some data, you first create a migration like `php artisan make:migration add_address_to_users`. And in the created file, you just add a column in the table like this.

```php
Schema::table('users', function($table){
   $table->string('address');
});`
```

And on the command line, you just type `php artisan migrate`. You will see that your data will not be erased and the new field has been added

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is the expected behavior of this command. If you want to run only perticular table then,

Copy your migration file to a temporal folder "temp" in migrations folder, then run (paths as in L5):

php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/temp

This way it will only run that file without messing with your current tables.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the single table which is already created using previous migration also delete the migration name from migrations table, then your migration will execute without deleting the record.

Answer (score 1):

Clean all :

> php artisan migrate:fresh

Clean a specific table

> php artisan tinker then  App\Post::truncate()